# Creating a Cauchy Distribution on R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, distribution

I am doing part c) of [image: this question] which requires the Cauchy distribution. This was my attempt:

```
counter <- 0
slopes <- c()

while(counter < 1000) {
  xvals <- runif(n = 100, min = -1, max = 1)
  evals <- rcauchy(100)
  y <- 5 + 3 * xvals + evals
  fit <- lm(y ~ xvals)
  slopes <- c(slopes, fit$coefficients[[2]])
  counter <- sum(counter, 1)
}
mean(slopes)
print(evals)
plot(evals)
```

However, I got some very strange results, and I'm doubting if they're correct:

[image: plot of evals]
[image: histogram with values of the slopes of 10,000 regression lines]
[image: first random set with regression line]

I also tried setting evals <- (x, location = 0, scale = 1, log = FALSE)  but that doesn't work. I just don't understand the difference between dcauchy and rcauchy, and how to get the error to be Cauchy distributed. Can anyone explain the weird results?

Comment: Your code and plots are correct.

Comment: What do you know about the Cauchy distribution?

Comment: To be honest, not much. I just know it looks like a Gaussian, but with a higher concentration around the tails, so I expected slightly more variation than the normal distribution that I had plotted before but not much, and definitely not a graph going all the way to a -300 slope! Does the Cauchy lead to that much randomness?

Comment: look at the moments (e.g. mean, variance, etc) of the cauchy distribution, they're undefined/infinite!  basically cauchy is about as bad as you can get...  models tend to break pretty quickly when you get cauchy distributed data

Comment: That is crazy! I don't understand how that's possible, but I'll definitely read up on it. At least I'm glad the plots are okay. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam you can get way more crazy than the Cauchy...

Comment: @Glen_b examples are good! Cauchy is interesting to me because of the places it turns up, e.g. divide two standard normals and you get Cauchy.  a Student's t-distribution with one degree of freedom is also Cauchy which helps intuit why regularisation helps

Comment: The Cauchy turns up in physics as well. I don't know of simple situations that produce the more extreme examples (at least not that I can think of at the moment) but for example there's a whole collection of [stable distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) (of which the Gaussian and Cauchy are two examples) -- the Cauchy is "in the middle" of the stability parameter's bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as noted in the comments, your code is doing the "right thing", however you might need to adjust your intuitions about the importance of what happens in the tails

as for as the difference between functions:

- `rcauchy` draws random values from the Cauchy distribution
- `dcauchy` is the "[probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)" for the Cauchy distribution

there are various sets of related bits of code that follow this convention, `rnorm` and `dnorm` for normal distribution, but you could see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/157662/17060 for some more commentary about the difference